# How to make a button change from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0 in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new in AS3 and i would like to make a button that connects with a dynamic text and whenever I press the button the content of the dynamic text changes from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to store if the button was pressed, and add a listener to the button.
When the button it's pressed, it will call the callback function.
There, check the value of the variable, and assign the corresponding values to the textfield

```
var wasPressed:Boolean = false;

yourButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClickedButton);

function onClickedButton (evt:MouseEvent):void {
    yourTextField.text = (wasPressed)?"0":"1";
    wasPressed = !wasPressed;
}
```